# How to align imageViews which are created dynamically inside a class and not the xml file

Tags: java, android

My Problem: I want to create a for loop in the onCreate() method to save imageViews dynamically. I am being able to do everything properly it's just that the imageView is displayed at the top left most corner, i.e i am not being able to assign it it's alignment.

My Code:

```
RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setMaxHeight(200);
        image.setMaxWidth(200);
        //CODE TO ADD THE ALIGNMENT OF THE IMAGE
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
        layout.addView(image);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setMaxHeight(200);
        image.setMaxWidth(200);
        //CODE TO ADD THE ALIGNMENT OF THE IMAGE
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
        layoutParams.setMargins(40, 40, 40, 40);
        image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        layout.addView(image);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The legal values can be found at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTextAlignment(int)

But this has no effect on an ImageView.  I'm not sure what you're actually truing to do, so I can't help you.  My best guess is you're trying to arrange views within the parent layout somehow, but to help with that we'd need to know the type of layout the parent is and what you want to do.

Comment: I am working on relative layout and now that i have successfully created an image and stored it in the layout using the for loop, i want to align each image in the layout but don't know how to do it dynamically i.e inside the onCreate() method and not inside the activity_main.xml

Comment: When you add it to the patent, create a custom RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and add the rules to it you would have added if this was xml.  Then use the 2 parameter version of addView

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response. I believe that what you asked me to do is something on the similar lines of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
yourImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); . How do i add my rules to this RelativeLayout.LayoutParams as if this was xml? I am not being able to get that part. Suppose i wanted the layout height as 200dp, the width as match_parent, and the margin_Top as 40dp, how will i pass this as an argument?

Comment: Look at addRule function of the relative layout layout param class